How to connect to a SMB shared printer with PowerShell
We attempt to connect to a SMB shared printer in Windows 11. We follow the instruction in the documentation but get an error when conneting:
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\server.global\location-printer

The error is:

Add-Printer : The specified server does not exist, or the server or printer name is invalid. Names must not contain the characters "," or "". On Line:1 Characters:1

Add-Printer -ConnectionName \cs-prt-s04.sbw.global\RH-NMFollowMeDupl ...

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_Printer:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer) [Add-Printer], Ci mException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070709,Add-Printer




If we open \server.local in the File Explorer the printer location_printer is listed.

Why are you specifying the server's domain? That is specifically what the error is referencing. Have you tried using quotes around the server/printer string?

@music2myear yes have tried that as well. Our printer shares are on the same domain (.global) but on different servers
